# Applying Fisher's exact test to compare non-binary parameter in two datasets

Tags: biostatistics, fishers-exact-test

I try to understand the reason authors of [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article-lookup/doi/10.1093/molbev/msm234) use exact fisher's test. They analyse characteristics (intron density) of genes from two datasets, plastid and ancestral and arrive at the conclusion that

"the density of introns in plastid genes ... calculated either per gene ... by comparing the means or the entire density distributions across the plastid and ancestral gene sets, was slightly but significantly lower than the respective densities in the ancestral genes".

So i wonder what is in Fisher's table in this case. Do we have datasets as rows, and what is in columns? Intron density is not binary, this value is specific for each gene.
Here is the table with exact data, p-value calculated using exact fisher's test

[image: Here is the table with exact data, p-value calculated using exact fisher's test]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that they did this:

```
> y
     [,1]  [,2]
[1,] 1543  6609
[2,] 7904 44989
> fisher.test(y)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  y
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.250213 1.411978
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.328884
```

However, in my opinion, this is not a valid statistical test in this context. The counts in the 2x2 table are not independent because the introns (counted in the second row) are a subdivision of the genes (counted in the first row). The researchers should have computed the number of introns per gene, and then conducted a two sample test on these numbers.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I think they refuse t-test due to intrones density isn't normally distributed. They use t-test hereafter to validate difference between medians of intron density only.

Comment: @atgc There are many two sample tests that can be used non-normal data. A two sample test does not have to be a t-test.